# Iterating and Searching value in a text file in c#

Tags: c#

I have a scenario where in a folder I have multiple text files and in the text files there are multiple tags. I want the value of the tag FromMailBoxText as shown below. Also this tag is occurring multiple times in a single text file.

```
<FromMailBoxText>abc@xyz.com</FromMailBoxText>
```

Any idea how we can retrieve this.

Thanks,
Harshit Verma

Comment: You can load the text files and use regex to find all lines with the tag FromMailBoxText. I'm on mobile so I can't show you how but if you are familiar with filestreaming and regex it can be done.

Comment: First what have you tried?  Second what exactly do you mean by "tag"  Is that just a line of text in the file?

Comment: tag as an xml tag <FromMailBoxText>abc@xyz.com</FromMailBoxText>

Answer (score 0):

c:\temp contains two files "a.txt" and "b.txt" with lines containing ".."

```
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\temp"))
        {
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(file), @"<FromMailBoxText>(?<sender>.*)</FromMailBoxText>"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["sender"].Value);
            }
        }
```

Prints:

```
abc@xyz.com
def@boo.com
```

Comment: And if he only wants the value inside the tag the only thing that hast to do is to replace and trim in order to quit the tags and white spaces...

Comment: replace @"^FromMailBoxText\s.+" with @"<FromMailBoxText>(.*?)</FromMailBoxText>". Tags were deleted by stackoverflow editor.

Comment: The above regex method worked perfectly but I have one more query that if a field has a action value like <FromMail action="Mail">xyz@abc.com</FromMail> then how to recover the action value from the above regexquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to parse more than 1 tag to obtain the values, maybe you can need

1. Xml Deserializer or
2. XmlReader to read the values
3. do what @Marius said, read the values with a regular expression
4. Use ANTLR
   and create your grammar to read what you need in the format you need